# Picking first X digits in string and replace each digit with Character

Tags: android, regex, kotlin

I'm trying to replace all digits in a string with an *.

Right now i have this

```
val regex = "^[\\d+].{8}"
val pattern = Pattern.compile(regex)
code = code.replace(pattern.toRegex(), "*** *** *")
```

It kinda works, but i want to have `*` instead of `"*** *** *"`
so the idea is to replace single digits instead of a block.

example string:

> 123 456 789 0

Comment: I might've misunderstood you, but if you only want to replace one, there's `replaceFirst`. Also, your current regex matches any number of digits, followed by any char 8 times. If you're looking to only replace digits, you'll need to add a capture group to exclude the the rest. I.e. `"""^\d*(.{8})"""` replaced with `*$1"`

Comment: I want to replace each occurrence of a digit with an * until i have replaced 8 digits, my final string should look like "*** *** *89 0"

Comment: And if there are fewer than 8 digits?

Comment: The string will always have the same size

Comment: You don't replace 8 digits in the example though, you only replace 7. Either way, `(0 until 7).forEach { raw = raw.replaceFirst("\\d".toRegex(), "*") }` is considerably less prone to error, and supports different formats as well. And might be slightly faster. Unfortunately, the replace method currently doesn't have a count. I can't think of any regex off the top of my head that does this accurately when it involves spaces without replacing with the full count manually. But if the string style is always the same, just `"*** *** *" + rex.substring(9)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A readable regex approach  is to match any amount of chars from the start of the string up to the 8th digit and then pass the match to a block and replace the second time with a digit pattern:

```
val s = "123 456 789 0"
val regex = """^(?:\D*\d){8}""".toRegex()
println(s.replace(regex) { it.value.replace(Regex("""\d"""), "*") })
// => *** *** **9 0
```

See the [Kotlin demo online](https://rextester.com/GBE51563)

The `^(?:\D*\d){8}` regex matches

- `^` - string start
- `(?:\D*\d){8}` - 8 repetitions of:

  - `\D*` - 0  or more chars other than digits
  - `\d` - a digit.

Just FYI, you may achieve the same with a hardcoded version with eight capturing groups, `s.replace("""^(\D*)\d(\D*)\d(\D*)\d(\D*)\d(\D*)\d(\D*)\d(\D*)\d(\D*)\d""".toRegex(), "$1*$2*$3*$4*$5*$6*$7*$8*")` if you always have 8 digits in the input string.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than a regex, you probably just want to iterate `n` number of times until you've replaced the desired number of characters. Using a functional approach you could do something like:

```
fun String.redact(numDigits:Int = 8): String {
    val charArray = toCharArray()

    charArray.withIndex()
        .filter { (_, char) -> Character.isDigit(char) }
        .take(numDigits)
        .forEach { (index, _) -> charArray[index] = '*' }

    return String(charArray)
}
```

Then:

```
println("123 456 789 0".redact()) // *** *** **9 0
```